# Vote close migrate to Server Fault

Tags: support

I want to vote for migration of this question to server fault as its really a question about server configuration, however its not available from the list in the `Close > Off-topic > Migration` box

[image]

Comment: Flag -> Custom -> Say that it's appropriate for serverfault.com

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150206/189912

Comment: I thought that you weren't supposed to mark a question as duplicate if the referenced question was unanswered? Anyway, this is a great question. Server Fault is one of the original triology sites and yet they have migration for Tex SE now but not Server Fault?? A custom flag is a very poor substitute. You need other users to see the migration vote and then contribute theirs if they agree and having it as a migration site automation the migration process.

Comment: I think Server Fault should be a standard migration path.